# cannot open file libboost_thread_vc-100-mt-gd-1_48.lib

Tags: c++, boost, dll, qt-creator

On compiling my program in Qt Creator I m getting linker error

```
:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib'
```

I add the following lines in the .pro file for the same

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_48

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage
```

I still have get the same error so I rebuild the library

```
C:\boost_1_48_0>bjam.exe --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete link=shared runtime-link=shared --with-thread --clean
C:\boost_1_48_0>bjam.exe --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete link=shared runtime-link=shared --with-thread
```

On using static library

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/ -llibboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage

win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48.lib
```

I get some more errors

```
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48.lib(thread.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48.lib(thread.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48.lib(thread.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static unsigned int __cdecl std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max(void)" (?max@?$numeric_limits@I@std@@SAIXZ) already defined in libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48.lib(thread.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static __int64 __cdecl std::numeric_limits<__int64>::max(void)" (?max@?$numeric_limits@_J@std@@SA_JXZ) already defined in libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48.lib(thread.obj)
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib'
    link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.1\lib" /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"debug\Player.intermediate.manifest" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /OUT:debug\Player.exe @C:\Users\vickey\AppData\Local\Temp\Player.exe.948.15.jom
    c:\qt\4.8.1\bin\qmake.exe -spec c:\Qt\4.8.1\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010 CONFIG+=declarative_debug -o Makefile c:\cygwin\home\vickey\tunebasket\p2p\test\Player\Player.pro
    C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
```

Any Ideas what is wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
```

worked for me. The problem I guess was that linker was looking for  libboost_thread_vc-100-mt-gd-1_48.lib while I had configured boost_thread_vc-100-mt-gd-1_48.lib in my .pro file. Defining the macro makes it explicitly upload the library defined in the .pro file.